# How to read and display data from a csv file to html webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html coding. 
I want to read and display my csv file data to a webpage. Data in each row of csv file must be displayed in a separate line on webpage.
My current code doesn't display anything and I don't have any clue why is it not working properly.
Please help me in this regard.
My code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allText =[];
    var allTextLines = [];
    var Lines = [];

    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "D:\PycharmProjects\filename.csv", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        allText = txtFile.responseText;
        allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    };

    document.write(allTextLines);<br>
    document.write(allText);<br>
    document.write(txtFile);<br>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following javascript for read and display data from csv file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('/file-path/demo.csv', function(data) {
var build = '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">\n';
var head = data.split("\n");
for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
build += "<tr><th>" + head[i] + "</th></tr>";
for(var i=1;i<head.length;i++){
build += "<tr><td>" + head[i].split("\n") + "</td></tr>";
}
}
build += "</table>";
$('#wrap').append(build);
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the `allTextLines` array as soon as your document is loaded

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.onload = function() {
    allText = txtFile.responseText;
    allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    for(var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += allTextLines[i];
        document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>';
    }
}

txtFile.open("get", "filename.csv", true);
txtFile.send();
```

where `filename.csv` should be put in your server static resources

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by server static resource?

Comment: this is where your static resources (like javascript/css/image files) are served

Comment: In which folder should I place my csv file?

Comment: I am new to javascript and css :( Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: I am using wamp server 64

Comment: I placed my file in www folder of wamp but still no data is being read and displayed on my html page :'(

Comment: CSV and HTML files are in same directory but no data is being displayed