# How to display name and year data from CSV file to HTML under DIV tag

Tags: html, css, csv

[image]

In this image under recommend button there is a div section in that div section i need to display songs from csv file as link or with button, when the user presses the song the song must be displayed in queue

I tried using Django to display CSV data via python but didn't work either

This is my current html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Music Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="float-container">

        <div class="float-child">
          <p>Queue</p>
          <div class="playlist">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="float-child">
          <p>Music Player</p>
          <p><button>Recommend</button></p>
          <div class="Songs">
              
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [Javascript File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API) should be helpful in your case. There's also an example on that page how to open/read a file. After reading the file contents (CSV is basically just text), you have to convert your CSV data to some sort of array or object in Javascript. Then you can output the data where it's needed

Comment: hello friend maybe this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637226/how-to-read-and-display-data-from-a-csv-file-to-html-webpage